# Scaling wide range datas in scikit learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to use a MLPregressor from scikit learn in order to do a non linear regression on a set of 260 examples (X,Y). One example is composed of 200 features for X and 1 feature for Y.

[File containing X](https://1drv.ms/t/s!AoDc-jhTwZFqijZSv8mhtxNDr-ZE)

[File containing Y](https://1drv.ms/t/s!AoDc-jhTwZFqijU7OxzoBHQw4XlT)

The link between X and Y is not obvious if directly plotted together but if we plot x=log10(sum(X)) and y=log10(Y), the link between both is almost linear.
As a first approach, I tried to apply my neural network directly on X and Y without success.

I have read that scaling would improve regression. In my case, Y is containing datas in a very wide range of values (from 10e-12 to 10e-5). When computing the error, of course 10e-5 as much more weight than 10e-12. But I would like my neural network to correctly approximate both. When using a linear scaling, let's say preprocessing.MinMaxScaler from scikit learn, 10e-8 ~ -0.99 and 10e-12 ~ -1. So I'm loosing all the information of my target.

My question here is: what kind of scaling could I use to get consistent results?
The only solution I have found is to apply log10(Y) but of course, error is increased exponentially.

The best I could get is with the code below:

```
    from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
    from sklearn.svm import SVR
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"]=(20,10)

    freqIter=[]
    for i in np.arange(0,0.2,0.001):
        freqIter.append([i,i+0.001])
#############################################################################

    X = np.zeros((len(learningFiles),len(freqIter)))
    Y = np.zeros(len(learningFiles))

    # Import X: loadtxt()
    # Import Y: loadtxt

    maxy = np.amax(Y)
    Y *= 1/maxy
    Y = Y.reshape(-1, 1)

    maxx = np.amax(X)
    X *= 1/maxx

    #############################################################################

    reg = MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=(8,2),  activation='tanh', solver='adam', alpha=0.0001, learning_rate='adaptive', max_iter=10000, verbose=False, tol = 1e-7)

    reg.fit(X, Y)

    #############################################################################

    plt.scatter([np.log10(np.sum(kou*maxx)) for kou in X],Y*maxy,label = 'INPUTS',color='blue')
    plt.scatter([np.log10(np.sum(kou*maxx)) for kou in X],reg.predict(X)*maxy,label='Predicted',color='red')
    plt.grid()
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

**Result:**

[image]
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Log seems like a good fit for all data, what's the problem?

Comment: First, you can see that my approximation sin't good, especially between 0 and 1. And then, making an error in logarithmic scale increases dramatically the error in normal scale. I was expecting scikit learn to have some tools but I can't find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found something interesting that is working well on my case.
First, I've used a log scaling for Y. I think it is the most adapted scaling when the range of values is very wide such as mine (from 10e-12 to 10e-5). Target is then between -5 and -12.
Secondly, my error about scaling X was to apply the same scaling to all features. Let's say my X contains 200 features, then I was dividing by the max of all features of all examples. My solution here is to scale feature1 by the max of all feature1 through all examples and then to reapeat it for all features. This gives me feature1 between 0 and 1 for all examples instead of far less previously (feature1 could be betwwen 0 and 0.0001 with my previous scaling).
I get better results, my main issue now is to select the correct parameters (number of layers, tolerance,...) but this is another problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at a [`FunctionTransformer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#custom-transformers). The example given applies a logarithmic transformation as part of pre-processing. You can also do it for an arbitrary mathematical function.

I would also suggest trying a ReLU activation function if you scale logarithmically. After the transformation your data looks fairly linear, so it may be converge a little faster -- but that's just a hunch.

Comment: Thanks I think I won't get further on the scaling. But as you can see on my results, I don't fit correctly when log10(sum(X)) is between 0 and 1 (and so Y is around 10e-12). But if I also scale my inputs X, I loose my relationship log(sum(X)) and have sum(log(X)) that is not working. Any other tip?

Comment: It's a shot in the dark, but you may want to try [polynomial features](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#generating-polynomial-features) after logarithmic scaling. That may allow you to try and model the noise around the logarithmic fit.

Comment: With 200 features, this would represent 1.6e60 features after rescaling. I think it is too much even if the idea sounds good. Or maybe I didn't understand how this rescaling is working.

Comment: If you have a lot of features, you may want to look into some of sklearn's [dimensionality reduction](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/unsupervised_reduction.html) methods instead. Generating polynomial features is the opposite in a sense -- it augments the features so you can try to model hidden interactions.

Comment: Ok but dimensionality reduction means loosing information. In my X are presented value of Spectrum for each range of frequency. Reducing dimensionnality means loosing information on some ranges of frequencies. Actually my main issue is to find a smart scaling on my inputs X so that I can match my Y correctly. In some cases, X features are very small and induces a very small Y. As I apply log10(Y), Y is correctly scaled. But if I apply log10(X), I'm loosing my linearity. I don't know what to do...